# How can I color the elements of the largest strongly connected component in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, legending

The following `Code`:

```
Clear[n, mm, eff, cau, maxRange, ce, deg45, vLabels];
SeedRandom[18];
n = 17;
mm = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
selectBetween[θ1_, θ2_] := 
BoolEval[θ1 <= mm < θ2];
vLabels = {1 -> AGR, 2 -> FIS, 3 -> CO1, 4 -> CO2, 5 -> MA1, 6 -> MA2,
7 -> EGW, 8 -> CST, 9 -> WHS, 10 -> HOT, 11 -> TSC, 12 -> FIN, 
13 -> EST, 14 -> ADM, 15 -> EDU, 16 -> HLT, 17 -> OSER};

Manipulate[
sa = SparseArray[selectBetween[θ1, θ2]*mm];
wG = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"],
DirectedEdges -> True, EdgeStyle -> LightGray, 
PlotLabel -> θ1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < θ2, 
VertexLabels -> vLabels];
SCCs = ConnectedComponents[wG];
sccLargest = MaximalBy[Length]@SCCs // Flatten;
ao = {0, 0};
eff = Total[selectBetween[θ1, θ2]*mm];
cau = Total[Transpose[selectBetween[θ1, θ2]*mm]];
maxRange = Max[Max[cau], Max[eff]]*1.2;
ce = ListPlot[Table[{cau[[i]], eff[[i]]} -> i, {i, 1, n}] /. vLabels,
AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
LabelingFunction -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]];
f[x_] := x;
deg45 = ListLinePlot[
Table[{f[x], x}, {x, -0.05, maxRange*1.2, 0.01}], 
PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
Grid[{
{θ1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < θ2, 
 Show[{ce, deg45}, PlotRange -> All, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], AxesOrigin -> ao, 
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> 
   Directive[Thick, Black, FontColor -> Black, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> True], 
  AxesLabel -> {"Cause", "Effect"}]}
} // Transpose],
{{θ1, 0.025, "Threshold θ1 \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"≤\",\nFontFamily->\"Cambria\",\nFontSize->16,\n\
FontWeight->\"Plain\"]\)" <> 
ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm]}, 0.001, 1.5, 
0.001}, {{θ2, 0.085, 
ToString[Subscript[m, ij], TraditionalForm] <> "<\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontFamily->\"Cambria\",\nFontSize->16,\nFontWeight\
->\"Plain\"]\)Threshold θ2"}, 0.001, 1.5, 0.001},
FrameLabel -> 
Style["Impact structure of sectoral input-output multipliers", 
Medium], LabelStyle -> Bold
]
```

generates:

[image]

I want to give different color to elements of the **largest** `Strongly Connected Component` and create a legend for the largest SCC.

**An Example**

```
Clear[n, g, mm, SCCs, eff, cau, maxRange, ce, deg45];
SeedRandom@11;
n = 17;
g = RandomGraph[{n, 25}, DirectedEdges -> True];
mm = AdjacencyMatrix[g]*RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
SCCs = ConnectedComponents[g];
sccLargest = MaximalBy[Length]@SCCs // Flatten; (* {3,4,9,10,11,14,15} *)
eff = Total[mm];
cau = Total[Transpose[mm]];
maxRange = Max[Max[cau], Max[eff]]*1.2;
ce = ListPlot[Table[{cau[[i]], eff[[i]]} -> i, {i, 1, n}], 
AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
LabelingFunction -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]];
f[x_] := x;
deg45 = ListLinePlot[Table[{f[x], x}, {x, -0.05, maxRange*1.2, 0.01}],
PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}];
Show[{ce, deg45}, PlotRange -> All, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], AxesOrigin -> ao, Axes -> True, 
AxesStyle -> 
Directive[Thick, Black, FontColor -> Black, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> True], AxesLabel -> {"Cause", "Effect"}]
```

My question is: how can I show the elements {3,4,9,10,11,14,15} of the largest strongly connected component by using a different color in the following `ListPlot`?

[image]

Comment: Please, give a _minimal_ example. Most of the code is interface stuff and not required to understand the underlying problem.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: I will prepare an example and update my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Epilog`.

```
epilog = Table[{cau[[i]], eff[[i]]} -> i, {i, 1, n}] // 
  Select[MemberQ[{3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15}, Last@#] &] // 
  Map[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[First@#]} &];

ListPlot[Table[{cau[[i]], eff[[i]]} -> i, {i, 1, n}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 LabelingFunction -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic], Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Comment: It works very nice. How can I add a `Legend` for Red points to indicate that they belong to the set of the largest strongly connected component? Thanks very much for help.

Comment: Add `PlotLegends -> 
 PointLegend[{Directive[Red, PointSize -> Large]}, {"Largest SCC"}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
coords = Transpose[Total[mm, {#}] & /@ {2, 1}];
rules = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, coords];
```

You can separate the input list into two groups using [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and use `PlotStyle` to style each group:

```
lists = Values @ GroupBy[rules, MemberQ[sccLargest, Last@#] &];

ListPlot[lists,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red},
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 PlotLegends -> {"others", "sccLargest"}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {maxRange, maxRange}}]}]
```

[image]

Replace `"others"` with `None` in `PlotLegends` to get

[image]

Replace `PlotTheme -> "Detailed"` with `PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "OpenMarkersThick"}` to get

[image]

Alternatively, you can add the option `PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}` to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use Style wrapper with MapAt:

```
ListPlot[MapAt[Style[#[[1]], Red] -> #[[2]] &, 
  Table[{cau[[i]], eff[[i]]} -> i, {i, 1, n}], List /@ sccLargest], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 LabelingFunction -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]]
```

or

```
ListPlot[Thread[
  MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, Transpose[{cau, eff}], List /@ sccLargest] ->
    Range[n]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, maxRange}, {-0.05, maxRange}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 LabelingFunction -> Callout[Automatic, Automatic]]
```